# jQuery div to fill viewport and resize not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using this jQuery to get the size of the viewport and set the div to this size:

```
    $("#hero").height($(window).height());
       $(window).resize(function(){
          $("#hero").height($(window).height());
    });
```

Here is my HTML:

```
    <section id="hero">
        Content here
    </section>

    <section class="showcase">
        Content here
    </section>
```

And my CSS:

```
body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 border: 0;
 background: #f5f6f7;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
}

section {
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
}

#hero {
 background: black; 
}

.showcase {
     background: blue;
     height: 500px;
}
```

I can't tell why this isn't working - i'm quite new to javascript / jQuery so maybe i'm missing something fairly obvious.

Basically what happens is - when the page loads the div looks like this:

[image: First state of page reload]

(the div is only wrapping the 'content here' content - eg. has no height set)

As soon as I grab the bottom of the browser window and resize it, the div fills the viewport - but I want the div to fill the view port straight away, and then allow me to scroll down to the next div.

Here is a code pen with my code - however, the code seems to work on this code pen!?

http://codepen.io/maxwbailey/pen/xDGmy

Can someone offer a solution as to where I am going wrong? as my code doesnt work in Safari chrome or firefox, but it works in the Code Pen.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a [`ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) method around your jQuery so that it's executed *after* your HTML has been parsed by the browser.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#hero").height($(window).height());
          $(window).resize(function(){
              $("#hero").height($(window).height());
      });
  });
```

Comment: Doh! Thank you Adrift!

Answer (score 0):

**resize** working fine in your example.

i have test your code its working fine.

please try it by adding ready event :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          //put your jquery code here
});
```

Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.

The handler passed to **.ready()** is guaranteed to be executed after the **DOM** is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code. When using scripts that rely on the value of CSS style properties, it's important to reference external stylesheets or embed style elements before referencing the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `Demo`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mTXhR/1/)**

use window-resizing function

```
  $(window).resize(function(){
      $("#hero").height($(window).height());
```

});